# error Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1 at using nativescript-contacts plugin

Tags: android, permissions, nativescript, contacts

after creating project with blank typescript template and adding nativescript-contacts and nativescript-permissions plugins ,running the project with android platform cause this errors

```
F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally>tns run android --device NioshaAVD
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image NioshaAVD
Waiting for emulator device initialization...
Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier.
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watchPatterns\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watchPatterns\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 3.1.6
Executing before-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-shouldPrepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-prepare hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-prepareJSApp\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-contacts for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-permissions for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom'.
            > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom'.            > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Failed to build plugin nativescript-contacts :
Error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
Executing after-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Stopping tsc watch
Executing after-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
Executing after-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing after-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch

F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally>tns run android --device NioshaAVD
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image NioshaAVD
Waiting for emulator device initialization...
Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier.
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watchPatterns\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Executing before-watchPatterns hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watchPatterns\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 3.1.6
Executing before-watch hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-shouldPrepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-prepare hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from F:\AMZONE-F\ProjectMobile\Tally\hooks\before-prepareJSApp\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-contacts for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-permissions for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.pom
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.1/support-v4-27.0.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Mehdizadeh-PC/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.pom
    - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :
```

i added this to dependencies , permisssion plugin was there but contacts no!

```
 {
        "name": "nativescript-contacts",
        "directory": "..\\..\\node_modules\\nativescript-contacts"
    }
```

also i added this to build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
      dependencies {
     implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1"
      }
}
```

also i downloded support-v4 and support compat  file and put them manually in 
the path that in my system was mentioned at error log at searched locations and changed

```
 maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
```

to

```
 mavenlocal()
```

also i changed sdktargetversion to 27 while minversion was 17

but i still getting these errors
i cant resolve contact plugin

Comment: Which version of {N} you are using? Are you referring to the build.gradle from platforms directory?

Comment: hi , {N} version is 5.0.1 should i upgrade it ? and yes my point is  build.gradle in platforms/android

Comment: There is no point in modifying anything inside `platforms/android` as they are compiled / auto generated files. All your changes / source code will be limited to app folder and gradle files inside `App_Resources`. Do you have all the android support libraries in place?